# Zip and Explode multiple Columns in Spark SQL Dataframe

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, user-defined-functions, apache-spark-dataset

I have a dataframe of the following structure:

```
A: Array[String]   | B: Array[String] | [ ... multiple other columns ...]
=========================================================================
[A, B, C, D]       | [1, 2, 3, 4]     | [ ... array with 4 elements ... ]
[E, F, G, H, I]    | [5, 6, 7, 8, 9]  | [ ... array with 5 elements ... ]
[J]                | [10]             | [ ... array with 1 element ...  ]
```

I want to write a UDF, that

1. Zips the elements on i'th position on each column in the DF
2. Explodes the DF on each of these zipped tuples

The resulting column should look like this:

```
ZippedAndExploded: Array[String]
=================================
[A, 1, ...]
[B, 2, ...]
[C, 3, ...]
[D, 4, ...]
[E, 5, ...]
[F, 6, ...]
[G, 7, ...]
[H, 8, ...]
[I, 9, ...]
[J, 10, ...]
```

At the moment I'm using a multi-call (one per column name, list of column names is collected before during runtime) to a UDF like this:

```scala
val myudf6 = udf((xa:Seq[Seq[String]],xb:Seq[String]) => {
  xa.indices.map(i => {
    xa(i) :+ xb(i) // Add one element to the zip column
  })
})

val allColumnNames = df.columns.filter(...)    

for (columnName <- allColumnNames) {
  df = df.withColumn("zipped", myudf8(df("zipped"), df(columnName))
}
df = df.explode("zipped")
```

Since the dataframe can have hundreds of columns, this iterative call of `withColumn` seems to take a long time.

**Question(s): Is this possible to do with one UDF and a single `DF.withColumn(...)` call?**

**Important**: The UDF should zip a dynamic number of columns (read at runtime).

Comment: Any idea how to do it in PySpark?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use an `UDF` that takes a variable number of columns as input. This can be done with an array of arrays (assuming that the types are the same). Since you have an array of arrays it's possible to use `transpose` which will acheive the same results as zipping the lists together. The resulting array can then be exploded.

```scala
val array_zip_udf = udf((cols: Seq[Seq[String]]) => {
  cols.transpose
})

val allColumnNames = df.columns.filter(...).map(col)
val df2 = df.withColumn("exploded", explode(array_zip_udf(array(allColumnNames: _*))))
```

Note that in **Spark 2.4+** it would be possible to use [`arrays_zip`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/functions.html#arrays_zip-org.apache.spark.sql.Column...-) instead of an `UDF`:

```scala
val df2 = df.withColumn("exploded", explode(arrays_zip(allColumnNames: _*)))
```

Comment: Solved it using @Shaido's code (with changing the last row to `val df2 = df.withColumn("exploded", explode(array_zip_udf(array(columnNames.head, columnNames.tail : _*))))`)

Comment: Thank you very much, you saved me such a lot of time!

Comment: @D.Müller: Happy to help :) I fixed to answer a bit to avoid the `head`/`tail` part, this can be done by adding `map(col)` to the column names. (I forgot that `array` only accepts a `Seq[Column]` and not `Seq[String]`.)

Answer (score 0):

if you know and sure about your number of values in the array, below can be a one of the easier solution

```
select A[0], B[0]..... from your_table
union all
select A[1], B[1]..... from your_table
union all
select A[2], B[2]..... from your_table
union all
select A[3], B[3]..... from your_table
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply. I adapted my question, as the dataframe can contain arrays of different sizes (row-wise). I guess, that this solution would not work on such data, right? Sorry for the belated change of the question.